# If we need to use a custom ID in Rails, should we use FriendlyID or Primary Key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I need to create a product code which will be generated with a custom function. It will start with a letter, have the id of the category and then have a random 7 digit number. For this, I can set the `primary_key` to a string and generate the code or I can use FriendlyID. What might be the best for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: Use something like friendly_id

**The story now**:

Choosing a *natural* key for the primary_key of a table should always be measured well, it has an impact on your data model.

The first issue is regarding related records in other tables. If you will have related tables, the foreign key in those tables should also be VARCHAR and match your generated primary key. If you are not sure what to do, **avoid** custom primary keys.

Another issue in your question may be:

> It will start with a letter, have the **id of the category**

Is this **id** the primary key of a `Category` model? If it's the case, you are generating a key with DB isolation in mind, but re-tighting with this one. Think again for this one.

Go for a *slug* generated by your function, you will be free for the future. You may create a brand new algorithm and thus only do a once for all change of the slugs. You may even have 2 slugs, the old one which redirects to the new one, and the new one.